# Performance advantages of Vulkan command buffers contrary to OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, vulkan

I have a question regarding the supposed performance benefits Vulkan command buffers have over OpenGL:

As far as I know, the command buffers are supposed to save on all the validation & gpu command generation work that, in OpenGL, has to be done at every drawcall.

Now, if the command buffer is recreated every frame because there is at least some dynamic state wouldn't that completely diminish the advantages of the buffer because it would still have to do all those drawcall checks at least once for the new buffer?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

The principle performance advantage of Vulkan command buffers over OpenGL is that you can build them in different CPU threads rather than force all commands to happen on the same CPU thread. That's the main reason they exist.

Validation is not unimportant for performance, however. OpenGL is a (relatively) safe API. If you use it incorrectly, OpenGL implementations are required to detect this in most cases and fail in a safe way. This requires draw calls after state changes to check to see if the state has been changed in a way that breaks something, and error out should that happen.

Vulkan does *no validation* whatsoever. Vulkan has a lot of "valid usage" rules, but if you violate those rules, the implementation is in no way required to tell you about it. You just get undefined behavior. Middleware validation layers exist to check for at least some of those conditions, but those are entirely optional and must deliberately be turned on.

The only errors Vulkan gives you are for conditions that are not *usage* errors: out-of-memory (some other program could allocate all the GPU memory), device-lost (this can happen for plenty of reasons outside of your program's control), etc.

So for the purposes of validation, it doesn't matter if you're building the CB every frame. The implementation *never* checks to see if the commands you're sending are valid.

Comment: So, disregarding validation, is a drawcall inside a vulkan command buffer that is built every frame "faster" (as in, less cpu footprint) than a drawcall in OpenGL?

Comment: @Desperado17: "*disregarding validation*" Are you using the [extensions to turn OpenGL errors into UB](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#No_error_contexts)? If not, there's no point in disregarding a thing you can't turn off in one of the two APIs.

Comment: I know that in vulkan validation is in a different component that can be switched on and off. I just want to know if, other than validation, a drawcall is faster in vulkan than in opengl just because it and its preceding state calls are inside a command buffer.

Comment: @Desperado17: The two models of how to talk to a GPU are so fundamentally different that comparing the relative cost of these specific function calls is basically meaningless. What decisions are you trying to make based on this information?

Comment: I want to know whether command buffers have any advantages except that they can be created in advance or in parallel. As in, give the driver more means for optimization.

Comment: A lot of per-draw operations in OpenGL move into pre-built descriptor sets and PSOs for Vulkan. This isn't directly related to command buffers per se, but a big reason why there are fewer "commands" needed per draw. Recent Vulkan adding back in some more flexability, which increases the cost per draw though.

Comment: @solidpixel: "*which increases the cost per draw though*" Is there any documentation on the increased cost per draw? I assume you're talking about VK_shader_object, yes?

Comment: Also VK_KHR_dynamic_rendering. No documentation - it's going to be vendor specific - but intuitively "set more states from the application per draw command" takes more effort than "use this PSO I built earlier". The shader_object extensions sets some upper bounds on how much "more expensive" is acceptable to pass conformance if you read it.

Comment: @solidpixel: Dynamic rendering doesn't change how state works; it only changes how render passes work. If there is any overhead relative to render passes, it would be in the begin renderpass function. A pipeline knows that it will be used in dynamic rendering and a secondary CB for dynamic rendering has to have basic information about the dynamic rendering state. So the draw command would be basically unaffected.

Comment: Ah, wrong one - was thinking of VK_EXT_extended_dynamic_state.

Comment: @solidpixel: Fragmentation of pipelines into excessive amounts of dynamic state can lead to draw calls having to do some "extra" work. However, this will be *very* hardware dependent, as the primary draw-call work that needs to be done is bundling together any hardware-related state when only some of it has changed. It should also be noted that the "extra" work would still have been done, just at pipeline-bind time rather than at the time of the first drawing command. And it's still just the first draw after a state change that matters.

Comment: No disagreements here =0